# Check if a game object is in front of my player character. Player have angle of sight

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, angle

I am trying to detect if food object contains to my player object's sight, but angle is wrong. It is greater by 90.

So here is my code: I don't know what I am doing wrong really, objects in the same layer and parent.

```cs
var player = players[i];
var oneFood = food[j];
var foodToPlayer = oneFood.transform.position - player.transform.position;
var angle = Vector3.Angle(foodToPlayer, player.transform.forward);
Debug.Log(angle);
```

so if I in front of game object, it log 90. if I rotate my player to 90, it log 0.

Comment: Maybe the `forward` axis of the player is not aligned with the mesh itself. I didn't understand why you have a list of players and food, instead of single objects.

Comment: @Diego Penha 
because of it is multiplayer game. But I am testing with one instance of food and one player. So. Mesh looks ok, I rotate it by angle of joystick. I just suppose, maybe I rotate my player wrong.

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -directionAngle * Mathf.Rad2Deg, 0);

directionAngle I get from joystick. and mesh on the screen rotates right.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. I really just got wrong angle of mesh. Thanks for comment Diego Penha!